# Setting a variable for a given SSH host

Tags: ssh, environment-variables

In `ssh_config`, one can choose to export some environment variables to the host using `SendEnv`.

Is there also a way to force a given value for this variable, per host? For example, would it be possible to export variable `$FOO` with value `bar` only when connecting to host `example.com`?

Comment: Related: [How can I pass an environment variable through an ssh command?](https://superuser.com/q/48783/87805)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't give a specific *value* for an environment variable in `ssh_config`, but you can certainly send the existing environment variable only to specific hosts.

```
Host example.com
    SendEnv FOO
```

To complete the chain:

```
FOO=bar ssh user@example.com
```

Finally, the remote server must have the environment variable listed in `AcceptEnv` in its `sshd_config`.

```
AcceptEnv FOO
```

Comment: WHAT is precisely what you'd like to avoid?

Comment: Having to write an alias in order to send a variable with a given value.

Comment: Sorry, not much else you can do... unless you can get the computer to read your mind. :)

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions though ;-) What I'd have liked would been something like `SetVar FOO='bar'` in `ssh_config` ;)

Comment: The recurring case for me is that old systems don't support `TERM=tmux-256color` so I'd like a fallback per remote host (with wildcards).

Comment: Just a note for anyone else who runs into this (since this is one of the top search results for sshd and `SendEnv`) -- if you're caching your ssh connections using `ControlPersist`, ONLY the `SendEnv` variables from the INITIAL connection will exist.  If you want to chain multiple discrete `ssh` commands with different `SendEnv` vars, you cannot use `ControlPersist` (afaict)

Answer (score 32):

You can give a specific value by using `SetEnv` in your `~/.ssh/config`, e.g.

```
Host *
  SetEnv FOO=bar
```

As per `man ssh_config`:

> Directly specify one or more environment variables and their contents to be sent to the server. Similarly to `SendEnv`, the server must be prepared to accept the environment variable.

Assuming your server got the following line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_* FOO
```

Check also: `man ssh_config` and `man sshd_config`.

Comment: Note for the puzzled reader (like myself, when I first read this): This is new since OpenSSH 7.8, released in August of 2018, and it will take a while for it to become available to the average user through OS updates. (But once it does become common, it will be by far the best solution to the problem)

Answer (score 2):

You can set per host config values using .ssh/config file. For example:

```
Host example.com
SendEnv FOO
```

Note that server must also support it.

Answer (score 2):

I want to highlight the `SendEnv / AcceptEnv` answer and a different way to trigger it.

```
user1@host1 $ export LC_SECRET="pencil"
user1@host1 $ export LC_MAGIC="xyzzy"
user1@host1 $ ssh -o "SendEnv LC_*" user2@host2
user2@host2 $ echo $LC_SECRET
pencil
user2@host2 $ echo $LC_MAGIC
xyzzy
```

What's happening here is we're declaring environment variables called `LC_SECRET` and `LC_MAGIC`.
We've requested to send both `LC_SECRET` and `LC_MAGIC` to the remote host using `SendEnv`.
The remote host will accept it because it has the following rule in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

This is, obviously an exploit of the remote system that automatically accepts the `LANG` environment variable or **ANY** environment variable starting with `LC_`.

Hence, why I named my variables `LC_SECRET` and `LC_MAGIC`.

If you want to do it properly, the remote system will require `sudo` access for you to modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to append other environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to set the environment variables in the ssh command and run an interactive shell, eg. i'm trying to invoke an interactive shell with env-var 'MANWIDTH':

```
ssh example.com 'MANWIDTH=120 bash -li'
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a different value of the env variable than the value of the env in the shell:

```
Host host
    ProxyCommand ENV=value ssh -W [%h]:%p
    SendEnv ENV
```