# SSH: Behavior of SetEnv for TERM variable

Tags: ssh, environment-variables

I want to set the TERM environment variable to a different value for each of my remote machines, so i used `SetEnv TERM=myTermForRemoteVar` in `~/.ssh/config`.
The remote machine still sees `TERM=myLocalTermVar`.

I added `AcceptEnv TERM` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the remote machine. No luck still.

I tried just for testing purposes `SetEnv FOO=smth` locally and `AcceptEnv FOO`. This works perfectly and the remote machine sees `FOO=smth`.

Is `TERM` treated specially by ssh? `SetEnv` works in general but not for `TERM`. Anyone else seeing this behavior? It is not documented at least. Is this a bug?

Comment: I must say I am experiencing the same behaviour in different variations of ssh servers and clients (as far as I remember). I was always too lazy to dig for the answers. I know there are workarounds (for others seeing this see for example https://serverfault.com/questions/302159/is-it-possible-to-change-value-of-term-when-calling-ssh ) but I am more interested in the rationale behind that particular behaviour and the explanation.

Comment: There is a patch to make it accept SetEnv TERM=... and do the right thing as of today :) https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/pull/224

Comment: I use this syntax for send custom TERM variable to remote host: `TERM=MyOwnTerm ssh host`

Comment: Good options are 1) to set TERM in remote system .bashrc or 2) change ENV before ssh as suggested by @oxyd with e.g. alias or shell script. 
1) e.g. 
if [ "$TERM" = "myLocalTermVar" ] ; then
        export TERM="myTermForRemoteVar"
fi
seems to work for bash

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**: Since OpenSSH 8.7 (2021-08-20), `SetEnv TERM` [is now supported](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.7):

> allow ssh_config SetEnv to override $TERM, which is
> otherwise handled specially by the protocol. Useful in ~/.ssh/config
> to set TERM to something generic (e.g. "xterm" instead of
> "xterm-256color") for destinations that lack terminfo entries.

---

[This thread on the openssh-unix-dev](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2018-November/037361.html) seems to indicate that `TERM` is indeed special, and you can't set it via `SetEnv`.  Here's my reading of things:

As noted in that thread, when the SSH client requests a new PTY from sshd, the request includes an explicit `TERM` value (see [RFC4254, "The Secure Shell (SSH) Connection Protocol", section 6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#section-6.2)).  This is separate from any environment variables the client wishes to send.

In OpenSSH's [`ssh.c`, function `ssh_session2_setup`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/5098b3b6230852a80ac6cef5d53a785c789a5a56/ssh.c#L2004),  OpenSSH unconditionally reads the PTY request's `TERM` value from your current environment, without any regard to any `SetEnv` directives.  (You can see environment variables, including those from `SetEnv`, being sent separately in [`clientloop.c`, function `client_session2_setup`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/5098b3b6230852a80ac6cef5d53a785c789a5a56/clientloop.c#L2318-L2370).)

Then, on the server side, [`session.c`'s `do_setup_env` function](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/5098b3b6230852a80ac6cef5d53a785c789a5a56/session.c#L988) sets up the environment for the new shell in the reverse order from how the client sends it: *first* it sets environment variables from `s->env`, *then* it sets `TERM` from the PTY request's `TERM` value (`s->term`), overwriting any value for `TERM` sent as a normal environment variable.

Because of this order of operations on the server, a `SetEnv TERM` will always be overridden by the value of `TERM` in the `ssh` client's environment, not from any `SetEnv`.

There seem to be good arguments for changing the behavior of OpenSSH in this regard in the aforementioned thread, but I take it no action came of it.  At least one person in that thread felt strongly that the remote host's init files should be the one to modify `TERM` if needed.  (I disagree, personally.)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer!

Comment: Thank you for the update @Lazarus535